# How can I test text colour with Jasmine when working in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jasmine

I am using JQuery to manipulate text on a HTML document and I need to test drive this process. However, I can't find anywhere syntax that would enable me to do this?

My code is:

```
$("#temperature").css({
    'color' : 'orange', 
    'font-size' : '200%'
});
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what it is you are asking...are you asking how to test that line of code?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to test the jQuery library instead of any logic in your code.  Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery:

```
toHaveCss(css)
  e.g. expect($('<div style="display: none; margin: 10px;">  
  </div>')).toHaveCss({display: "none", margin: "10px"})

  e.g. expect($('<div style="display: none; margin: 10px;">  
  </div>')).toHaveCss({margin: "10px"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery with jasmine

```
describe("check css ", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        // your initial expectation here
    });

    it ("should css check colour.", function() {
      expect($("#temperature")).toHaveCSS({'color' : 'orange', 'font-size' : '200%'});
    });
  });
```